# Laravel VueJS Router in backend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, vue-router

I'm working on a Laravel project where all frontend is managed by vuejs.

So, I have all backend routes defined on:

`routes/api.php`

And the file: `routes/web.php` it has this only route:

```
Route::view('{all}', 'app')
    ->where('all', '^((?!api).)*')
    ->name('vue');
```

Giving all the responsability to vue.js.

So inside `resources/js` (vue side) I have the frontend routes defined, for example:

```
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: home,
    meta: {
        auth: true,
    }
},
{
    path: '/invoices/show/:id',
    name: 'invoices.show',
    component: InvoicesShow,
    meta: {
        auth: true,
    }
},
```

Now the problem:

I started trying to create some notifications.

So on the notification I have to put the link where the customer has to go, but this link is to the frontend... So in Laravel I cannot write the vue.js route. Well, that's the question, is it possible to write the named route of vue.js?

I'd like to define this link on a notification for example:

```
->action('View Invoice', route('invoices.show', $invoiceId));
```

But the named route "invoices.show" it doesn't exist on Laravel routes. It's defined on vuejs router, in: `resources/js/router/routes.js`

So it won't work.

Is possible to get the vuejs router by name?

Comment: Can you explain a little better?, i don't get what you need exactly...

Comment: I improved the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I find impossible to do this.
So I simply write the full url "hardcoded".

```
->action('View Invoice', route('vue', ['all' => "invoices/show/{$invoiceId}"]));
```

This resolves my problem, but I cannot use the vue.js named routes.

Answer (score 0):

One of the dirty workarounds would be to leave the VueJs route as it is and to create a new identical "helper" route for Laravel in your `routes/web.php` file.

So your web.php would look like this:

```
Route::view('/invoices/show/{id}', 'app')->name('invoices.show');
//Here you can add additional "helpers" routes as needed

Route::view('{all}', 'app')
    ->where('all', '^((?!api).)*')
    ->name('vue');
```

In this case, VueJs would still work fine and you would be able to use `route()` helper function in your project but a disadvantage is that you would need to maintain two routes if there is any changes.